# Fingerprint in Android

Tags: android, encryption, fingerprint, android-keystore, android-fingerprint-api

I am curious whether we can share encrypted keypair generated with fingerprint template to the server in android or not. If  so, then

- I want to enroll the fingerprint first
- Store the keypair to server
- And at the runtime, I want to verify the fingerprint from an Android device with that keypair

Is it possible to do so?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Your fingerprints are everywhere, at the police, in the airports, in the glasses you touch and even the money that you pay...

Comment: Of course it's possible (except for the _"generated with fingerprint template"_ part). See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53853910/do-i-need-cryptoobject-object-or-null-for-the-following-use-case-during-fingerp/53866367#53866367

Comment: Could you please more clear? So, you want to create keypair in Android device but also same time want to sent that keypair to the server right? It's not most common approach. In a security manner suggested way is, only sending the public part of the key to the server. And if you will use AndroidKeyStore as a keystore provider and if device has TEE, you can't even extract the key material from the keystore.